# Integrating Stripe to MeanJs boilerplate

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, stripe-payments

I am new to Mean stack and is using the ver 0.4.2 of MeanJS(meanjs.org). I am stuck at integrating Stripe to the platform. I am using [Stripe Angular](https://github.com/gtramontina/stripe-angular) for the integration.

So, far I have created a new controller. I have added the required files to the header already. The controller looks like this :

```
(function() {
'use strict';
angular
.module('availabilities')
.controller('StripepayController', StripepayController);

StripepayController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'];

function StripepayController($scope, $http) {
    $scope.saveCustomer = function(status, response) {
         //console.log('striped');
         $http.post('/stripecharge', { token: response.id });
    };
}
})();
```

I have created a view as the tutorial says. Added a route to the server routes page of my module :

```
// routes for stripe
app.route('/stripecharge')
.all(availabilities.stripePay);
```

The server controller has the following middleware:

```
exports.stripePay = function(req, res) {
var stripe = require('stripe')('secret_key');
var token = req.body.stripeToken;
var charge = stripe.charges.create({
    amount: 1000,
    currency: 'usd',
    description: 'Example charge',
    source: token,
}, function(err, charge) {
    // asynchronously called
});
};
```

The token is getting created, but i cannot charge the card. Any help as to how I go forward would be great.

Also if someone could explain how the submission of forms happen in MEANjs from the view to the server. I couldnt figure that out well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after much research and going back to the lessons, I finally fixed the issue. Thanks @floatingLomas for the help.

I was actually missing the referencing of the stripe node module in the server controller. Here's how my server looks now -

```
exports.stripePay = function(req, res) {
    var token = req.body.token; // Using Express
    // Charge the user's card:
    var charge = stripe.charges.create({
        amount: 1000,
        currency: 'usd',
        description: 'Example charge',
        source: token,
    }, function(err, charge) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(500, err);
        } else {
            res.send(204);
        }
    });
};
```

On top of the express controller i have added

```
var stripe = require('stripe')('My_Secret_key');
```

I was getting the error of 'stripe' not defined in the console as the node module was missing. Added the stripe node module using

```
npm install --save stripe
```

Everything seems to work like a breeze now.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use either [Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js) or [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) in your Angular app, and then POST the resulting Token to your Node.js endpoint.

Comment: Exactly thats what i am unable to understand.

Comment: How does your angular code work with Stripe.js or Checkout?  Does your server log contain anything?

Comment: Nope, it doesnt get logged, the token gets created though. I get to see token while logging it, but no other calls. I am unable to pass the call to server.

Comment: Are you sending the token to your server?  I.e., are you using that `StripepayController.saveCustomer` call as the stripeResponseHandler for Stripe.js?